# Django message recipient url

Tags: python, django

so i have django-messages installed on my website: https://github.com/arneb/django-messages

and it states in the docs "Messages can be composed and there is an easy, url-based approach to preloading the compose-form with the recipient-user, which makes it extremly easy to put "send xyz a message" links on a profile-page."

and I've found the url being ,

```
^messages/ ^compose/(?P<recipient>[\w.@+-]+)/$ [name='messages_compose_to']
```

however the docs give no information on how to implement this, i would like to be able to add send user a message on the profile page of each user however being so new to django i dont really unserdtand how to implement this.

i also found this in views.py

```
form = form_class()
        if recipient is not None:
            recipients = [u for u in User.objects.filter(**{'%s__in' % get_username_field(): [r.strip() for r in recipient.split('+')]})]
            form.fields['recipient'].initial = recipients
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'form': form,
```

Could someone please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: You are right. The docs don't seem to explain very much about how to use this library. You could try to ask this question on the github issue tracker. https://github.com/arneb/django-messages/issues

Comment: good idea, ill do that now